# Integration of a function with 3 parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions

```
Integrate[Y^(b - 1) (1 - Y)^(a - 1) (-Log [Y])^-k, {Y, 0, 1}, 
          Assumptions -> {0 < a, 0 < b, k != 0}]
```

`Integrate` doesn't evaluate and display the same thing as input. I want the output to be a function of $a$,$b$,$k$

Comment: "display the same thing as input" - usually, that means *Mathematica* doesn't know if your integral has a closed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get results if a values are element of the integers and k < a.

```
int[a_, b_, k_, assum___] := 
  Integrate[Y^(b - 1) (1 - Y)^(a - 1) (-Log[Y])^(-k), {Y, 0, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> 
      Join[{a > 0, b > 0, k \[Element] Reals, 
        a \[Element] Integers}, {assum}]]
```

Do integration for some integer a

```
Table[int[a, b, k], {a, 1, 5}]

(*   {ConditionalExpression[b^(-1 + k) Gamma[1 - k], k < 1], 
      ConditionalExpression[(b^(-1 + k) - (1 + b)^(-1 + k)) Gamma[1 - k], 
    k < 2], ConditionalExpression[(b^(-1 + k) - 
 2 (1 + b)^(-1 + k) + (2 + b)^(-1 + k)) Gamma[1 - k], k < 3], 
      ConditionalExpression[-(-b^(-1 + k) + 3 (1 + b)^(-1 + k) - 
  3 (2 + b)^(-1 + k) + (3 + b)^(-1 + k)) Gamma[1 - k], k < 4], 
      ConditionalExpression[(b^(-1 + k) - 4 (1 + b)^(-1 + k) + 
 6 (2 + b)^(-1 + k) - 
 4 (3 + b)^(-1 + k) + (4 + b)^(-1 + k)) Gamma[1 - k], k < 5]}   *)
```

you get integrals for k < a. Analysing the results gives the rule

```
s[a_] := Sum[(-1)^i Binomial[(a - 1), i] (i + b)^(-1 + k), {i, 0, 
              a - 1}]*Gamma[1 - k]
```

Proof this rule

```
Table[int[a, b, k, k < a] == s[a], {a, 1, 5}] // Simplify // TableForm

(*   True, True, True, True,True }
```

Now define the solution with k < a

```
int1[a_?IntegerQ, b_, k_] := 
  Sum[(-1)^i Binomial[(a - 1), i] (i + b)^(-1 + k), {i, 0, a - 1}]*
    Gamma[1 - k]
```

For integer k you have to take the limit  for example `Limit[int1[14, 11, k], k -> 2]`